# What do I need to do to be able to use Panda3D from my Python text editors?

Tags: python, panda3d

I just installed Panda3D, and I can run the example programs by double clicking them, but I can't run them from IDLE or Sublime. 
I get errors like ImportError: No module named direct.showbase.ShowBase
I some people bring this up before and the responses suggested using ppython, I can't figure out how run that from Sublime, and I really the auto complete function there.
How can I either configure the Python 2.7 version that I already have to run Panda3D programs or run ppython from SUblime?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your operating system. Panda3D uses the system's python on OS X and Linux and should "just work".

For Windows Panda3D installs its own copy of Python into Panda3D's install directory (defaults to C:\Panda3D I think), and renames the executable to ppython to prevent name collisions with any other python installs you might have. In your editor you have to change which interpreter it uses to the ppython.exe in the panda3d directory.